# Получение заголовков в DownloadManager Android

Tags: android

Друзья, выручайте! Надо проверять актуальность файла при загрузке с сервера (загружаются через системный DownloadManager в Android).
Актуальность файлов, при непосредственном обращении к ним, проверяется следующим образом:
1. При первой загрузке файла в заголовке передается некоторый хеш, уникальный для версии файла.
2. Этот хеш при загрузке следующего файла отправляется уже в заголовке с клиента.
3. Если хеш совпадает с серверным (файл не менялся), то возвращается ошибка 304.

Проблема в том, что после загрузки файла у меня не получается получить заголовки, которые пришли вместе с файлом. Как их можно вытащить? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Боюсь, что при загрузке через `DownloadManager` ничего не выйдет. Дело в том, что все данные, которые можно от него получить обратно, перечислены в константах, начинающихся с `COLUMN_`, их можно посмотреть в [документации по классу](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html). Заголовки, соответственно, не сохраняются.

Если есть возможность, я предлагаю грузить файлы самостоятельно, с сохранением всех заголовков, а потом добавлять их в менеджер загрузок через метод `addCompletedDownload`.